# Disable HikariPool logging

Tags: java, logging, hikaricp

This is perhaps a very simple question. How do i disable Hikari-CP debug logs? In my log file i have lots of these messages

```
DEBUG [.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:] - Before cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=0, avail=10, waiting=0)
DEBUG [.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:] - After cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=10, inUse=0, avail=10, waiting=0)
```

and in my log4jConfig.xml:

```
<logger name="org.zaxxer.hikari">
    <level value="error"/>
</logger>
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the logger configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The logger name should be `com.zaxxer.hikari` not `org.zaxxer.hikari`.

Comment: Doesn't work.  Still prints out the debug.  Annoyed!

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

WTF?
19:16:29.143 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)


#
log4j.logger.com.zaxxer.hikari=ERROR

Comment: @nitefrog Were you able to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

The class name is displaying in you DEBUG info:
DEBUG [.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:] - ...
here the class name is zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool, Just modify config file as being disaplayed.

I use logback logger, there is a file named logback.xml located in resources folder, to disable HikariPool logging, i write following config:

```
 <configuration>
...
    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use log4j properties, simple add these two lines:

```
log4j.category.com.zaxxer.hikari=INFO
log4j.logger.HikariPool=INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the levels of Hikari loggers dynamically:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;

public class App{
     public static main(String[] args) {
         Logger.getLogger("com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase").setLevel(Level.OFF);
         Logger.getLogger("com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool").setLevel(Level.OFF);
         Logger.getLogger("com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource").setLevel(Level.OFF);
         Logger.getLogger("com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig").setLevel(Level.OFF);
         Logger.getLogger("com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource").setLevel(Level.OFF);
     }
}
```

I have tested this on hikariCP 3.4.1 with log4j 1.2.17