# Hikari pool Disable debug mode

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, hikaricp

Hi to everyone I have to disable log information from `com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool`.
I've tried with

```
Logger.getLogger("com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

and with `<Logger name ="com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool" level="OFF"/>` in my log4j2.xml file

But I still see Debug message like this

```
14:19:47.557 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just for your information. Don't put *[SOLVED]* in the title, that's what the Accepted Answer is for. If your own answer helps you the most, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark (you may have to wait some time to accept an answer)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I'm new on this community and I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem creating "logback.xml" file with this code:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
            ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  `<Logger name ="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="OFF"/>`

[Referring to disable-hikaripool-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274115/disable-hikaripool-logging/27274833)

Comment: I tried that solution but it doesn't work. Actually it looks like my program doesn't use the log4j2.xml file.